# dealing with multiple player thread and repainting

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, game-engine

I am currently working on a java bomber-man game, the game works fine however I do have a concurrent modification exception which is thrown repeatedly.
In my game I have two players and each have their own thread which is run (`thread.run()`) at a constant 60fps using a timer. I tried having repainting run after bother thread run as well at the end of each player run method.

Method 1:

```
public void loop() {
    if (!gameover) {
        player1_thread.run(); //run player 1 thread
        player2_thread.run(); //run player 2 thread
        gui.repaint() //repaint panel
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
public class Player extends Character { //Character implements Runnable
...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        play();
        ...
        game.render();
    }
}
```

Both of these method throws the concurrent modification as expected so how can I avoid the error other then simply doing:

```
player1.run(); //call the run method of each player class
player2.run();
```

which gives player1 an advantage.

**EDIT:**

Method 4:

```
import java.util.Timer

public class Player extends Character { //Character implements Runnable
    private Timer gameTimer

    @Ovveride
    public void run() {
        gameTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                play();
                ...
                game.render();
            }

        }, 0, 1000/60);
    }
}

public class Game extends AbstractGame {

    private void init() {
        ...
        Thread player1_Thread = new Thread(player1);
        Thread player2_Thread = new Thread(player2);
        gui = new GameGraphics(this); //subclass of JPanel
        player1_thread.start();
        player2_thread.start();
    }

    /* this method is called at a constant 60fps(like the player timer) in the main game timer in my abstract game class */
    public void gameLoop(){
        if(!gameover){
            render();
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

This also throws the exception

Comment: This is not how you do threading in general. Usually you create a Thread and call its `start()` method.

Comment: Is this a networked multiplayer game or simply local?

Comment: @Michael it's a simple local game

Comment: Then I think the better solution is to not use threads at all. There's no inherent gain in using threads for this application.

Comment: I'm with @Michael. For instance, if this is a Swing GUI game, then consider using a Swing Timer for the game loop.

Comment: I updated the post, the start method also threw the exception, as for not using thread then whichever player play method is called first will have an advantage isn't it, like in this case player1.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong : Calling run() will execute instructions using the main thread.

Correct:  Call player1.start() to start a new thread, so that the run() {...} is executed in the newly started thread.

Answer (score 0):

If `Player` is a sub class of `Thread` you can start it with `.start()`, but do not start thread in a loop. You only have to start a thread ones, after that it will run till the run method in that class is completed, most likely you want to write a run method with a loop, so it keeps running till a point you stop it. If you want to run the game just with one thread you can implement `Runnable`, and do the thing you do right now, calling `run()` in a loop. There will then only be one main thread.

By just calling run on a thread object, you are not starting a thread, it just calls the run method in that object ones.

I think the best to do is, just one thread updating the paint with data out of a model. Change the data in this model from the player threads.

Comment: updated main post, the playerThread is a variable name for a Thread which takes the player in the constructor (refer to post for more detail)

Comment: I would remove the render function in the player class. Just let the 60fps gameloop update the paint.